# Custom chart axis, ticks and grid in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, grid, axis-labels

I'm developping a WinForms app in C# for plotting multiple lines on a logarithmic scale. I'm trying to display my data on a grid that would look like this:

[Logarithmic grid, with major and minor ticks at specified positions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F59JO.png)

The data I'm plotting matches specific values on the X-Axis (1, 2, 4, 8 and 16) but there's an offset on the axis (the origin is lower than 1 and the max value is greater than 16) because I have to plot several lines with error bars (I need some extra width).

I'm struggling to find a way to specify exact positions for where my major/minor ticks to be placed.
The closer I got was by specifying `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LogarithBase = 2` and `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LogarithBase = 2`, but since my origin is not set at `(1,1)` I get this as a result:

[The closer I got to the grid I'm looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnrbA.png)

Ideally, I'd like to have a collection of values that specifies the position of the ticks. How one could achieve that? I feel like I'm getting closer by using the `CustomLabel` class but I'm not in there yet.

Thanks!

I tried to add CustomLabels for specifying the ticks position but couldn't find a way to have the ticks placed at the position I specified: I only found a way to put ticks at specified "indexes" that I struggle to have placed at the correct positions.

I tried playing with the axis intervals too, with no success either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for so don't worry about accepting, but for you or anyone who happens to read this.  Using a 3rd party tool will make this easy, plus you can ask questions directly to the authors of the chart. Full disclosure, I own Gigasoft.

Instead of trying to force your chart to produce the grid in your current approach, instead, maybe your charting api has a feature to draw random annotations, lines, and text, and construct your own axes/grid via these lines and text.

For example, with Gigasoft ProEssentials, the x axis could be created as follows, the y axis would be similar.  This is based on our example 110 in our demo.

```
Pesgo1.PeGrid.Option.LogScaleExpLabels = false;  // optional 
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.TextSize = 100; // to match size of normal grid text
Pesgo1.PeGrid.Option.ShowXAxis = ShowAxis.NoNumbersOrLabels;  // hide default grid line labels 
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.BottomMargin = "X";  // used with below to add space of line annotation text outside grid 
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.ShowMargins = ShowMargins.Always;  // adds space for line annotation text

int n = 0;

// add grid lines with grid number labels 
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = 1.0;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridLine;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = "|h1";
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
n++;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = 2.0;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridLine;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] ="|h2";
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
n++;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = 4.0;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridLine;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = "|h4";
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
n++;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = 8.0;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridLine;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = "|h8";
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
n++;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = 16.0;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridLine;
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = "|h16";
Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
n++;
// add extra grid lines 11 - 15 
for (int x = 11; x <= 15; x++)
{
     n++;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = x;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.Dot;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(80, 200, 200, 200);
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = " ";
 }
 // add extra ticks 1 to 16
 n++;
 Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = 3.0;
 Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridTick;
 Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
 Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = " ";
 for (int x = 5; x <= 7; x++)
 {
     n++;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = x;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridTick;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = " ";
 }
 for (int x = 9; x <= 15; x++)
 {
     n++;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxis[n] = x;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisType[n] = LineAnnotationType.GridTick;
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisColor[n] = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 200, 200);
     Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Line.XAxisText[n] = " ";
 }
 // Set the x axis range 
 Pesgo1.PeGrid.Configure.ManualScaleControlX = ManualScaleControl.MinMax;
 Pesgo1.PeGrid.Configure.ManualMinX = .9;
 Pesgo1.PeGrid.Configure.ManualMaxX = 18;
 Pesgo1.PeAnnotation.Show = true;  // show the line annotations
```

And the resulting image is ...

[image]